# Is there a way to view the Dynasty Weapon skills?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Anyone know how to view the dynasty weapon skills? Staff of Sandro has a lot of lich-named skills but there's no indication what those skills do

Comment: I've updated my answer; I found a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fully detailed description of the dynasty weapon (and each of its 5 leveled abilities) can be seen (counterintuitively) on the Dynasty **Hero** screen, under the middle sub-tab.

This sub-menu lists all your currently unlocked dynasty weapons, progress towards leveling each of them, and the ability granted each level.

Right-clicking the ability will cause a description of it to appear. Not sure if this is applicable while *in* a game, but it's readily available from the main menu, at least.

Comment: Do passives appear in the spellbook too?

Comment: @Jonn If they're actual abilities instead of just stats (i.e., +Magic Power, or +Initiative), they should.

Comment: sweet. Gonna check it out later.

Answer (score 2):

Just go in your dynasty section when you start the game, you can see it in there.